# Is "S.Sgt." an Acronym or a Compound Noun?

Tags: etymology

Can anybody tell me the answer? Thanks.

Comment: What does it mean? Please provide a definition and an example of how it is used. Yes, I could do that for you, but I won't: that's your job.

Comment: Neither. It's an abbreviation.

Comment: It's an abbreviation (though not of the acronym variety) of 'Staff Sergeant', which _is_ a compound noun. Whether it makes sense to say 'S.Sgt. is a compound noun' depends on how loosely one is prepared to treat the language.

Answer (score 1):

It is an abbreviation of Staff Sergeant, also abbreviated as SSG in the U.S. Staff Sergeant is a rank and, due to its specificity, would be considered a compound noun. I would understand that, just as an acronym for a compound noun is not a compound noun itself, neither would the abbreviation for a compound noun be a compound noun.